# Unable to extract zip file when it contains 2GB txt file throws error java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid compression method

Tags: java, unzip

I have unzip code which is able to extract if zip file has 1.90 GB txt file init.
But not able to unzip when zip file contains 2GB text file.

Here code:
    /**
     * method unzip zip file near to 2GB not more than this.
     * provide zip file path and output folder all unzip file 
     * will be copied to the output folder
     */

```
public void unZipIt(String zipFile, String outputFolder)  {
    // create output directory is not exists
    File folder = new File(outputFolder);
    if (!folder.exists()) {
        folder.mkdir();
    }
    //extract zip if already present skip file from extraction
    try (ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(
            zipFile));) {

        ZipEntry ze = zis.getNextEntry();
        while (ze != null) {

            String fileName = ze.getName();
            File newFile = new File(outputFolder + File.separator
                    + fileName);
            if (!newFile.exists()) {
                new File(newFile.getParent()).mkdirs();
                ze = writeExtractedFile(zis, newFile);
                AutoLog.getLogger().info("File extracted: "+fileName);
            }
            else
            {
                AutoLog.getLogger().info("File aready present in directory so skip file:"+fileName);
                ze=zis.getNextEntry();
            }
        }
        zis.closeEntry();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Assert.fail("Fail to unzip zip file", e);
    }
```

}

```
/**
 * helper method for zip extract 
 * new created file in output folder this method will write the same data 
 * to this files. 
 */
private ZipEntry writeExtractedFile(ZipInputStream zis,
        File newFile) {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[10]; 
    ZipEntry ze = null;
    try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newFile)) {
        int len;
        while ((len = zis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
        ze = zis.getNextEntry();
        return ze;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Assert.fail("Fail to write extracted file", e);
    }
    return ze;

}
```

Comment: Could you provide your code, along with the JDK version you are using ?

Comment: The 2GB limit suggests it may be a HD encoding type problem (ntfs, fat32..).

Comment: Hi Berger, I'm using 64 bit machine and JDK version is 8. I have added code snippet.

Comment: You are magically exepecting the local variable `ze` declared in `unZipIt()` to become null or not null or different because of an assignment to the local variable `ze` declared in the method `writeExtractedFile()`, which is a different variable. It won't do that. You need to move the `zis.getNextEntry()` calls into the `unZipIt()` method.

Comment: after doing above that will not change results.

Comment: I did change still throws error i.e java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid compression method

Comment: Anyone knows about this how to resolve this issue..?